# nVidia GL 650M on Dell Inspiron n7720 with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dell, inspiron

I want to get 3D acceleration on my laptop, but the "Additional Drivers" tool doesn't give me any results. I have tried installing the "nvidia-current" package. After doing this, I fired up Minecraft just to test it, and got this exception:

```
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not init GLX
```

What is happening here? How can I get 3D acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install bumblebee. [Here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/216) you got all you need.

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answers a bit more with insight on why this is a solution, as opposed to simply saying "do this".

Comment: That page contains a big list of posts by people who have problems but can't seem to solve them. What exactly am I supposed to do?